# Wait popup window javascript

Tags: javascript, window, alert, wait

Basically I'm doing this:

```
 window.onload=function wait(){
     alert ("Please, wait until process has finished.");
     window.location="index.jsp";
 };
```

What I need is, an alert window, or something similar that will disappear/enable the "OK" button in the popup window, only after X seconds are passed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var popup = window.open('','pop','width=200px, height=10px'),
        popdoc, msg, script;
    if (popup) {
        popdoc = popup.document;
        msg = popdoc.body.appendChild(popdoc.createElement('p'));
        msg.innerHTML = 'Please, wait until process has finished.';
        script = popdoc.createElement('script');
        script.text = '(function () {setTimeout(function () {self.close();}, 3000);}());';
        popdoc.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

A demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwBCt/)

Comment: Actually this solution is close to what I was thinking... Not that "cool" but it works... what if I want to deny that window closing? How can I do that?

Comment: You could store a real HTML-page for the popup in your server, it's easier to include JS (and styles) in a real file... However, you can do this: `script.text = '(function () {window.delay = setTimeout(...`, and then (in the main page) just clear the `delay` using `popup.clearTimeout(popup.delay);`. A demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwBCt/1/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var wait = function() {
    alert ("Please, wait until process has finished.");
}
setTimeout(wait, 3000);
```

The 3000 is the miliseconds you want to wait before it calls the function.

Comment: what I need is a popup window that will istantly appears, and then disappears AFTER a while. Not a window that appear after some seconds...

Answer (score 0):

just pass the function to the the settimeout

```
setTimeout(yourfunction,2000);
```

this will run the function after 2 sec of the doc load

Comment: what I need is a popup window that will istantly appears, and then disappears AFTER a while. Not a window that appear after some seconds...